# Expressing, querying and enforcing constraints on graph contents

Tags: neo4j

Say you would like to create a graph authoring system that puts constraints on the contents of the graph. Say you have a "contains" relationship where "city" may contain "houses", which in turn contain "bedrooms" and "bathrooms". But it is not legal for a city to contain bedrooms or bathrooms, or for bathrooms to contain bedrooms.

Further, say you want to offer suggestions to graph author - if they select a "city" node, you might want to give them suggestions for what can be added to the city "houses", "hospitals" and "schools", but not "bedrooms".

I am guessing that these constraints, in and of themselves, could be represented as a graph. Has anyone had any luck doing that? What was your experience?

Comment: In terms of what Neo4j offers, with the free version you only get [unique property constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-introduction) which don't seem to apply to your desired constraints. AFAIK, Neo4j has no mechanism for what you're describing, but you could load the data that you have (or envision) and set up some routinely-executing queries to remove the relationships that are undesirable. E.g. `MATCH (b:Bedroom)<-[c:CONTAINS]-(ba:Bathroom) DELETE c;`, and analogously for the other disallowed relationships.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could express these rules, for example:

- You could use your application layer to check whether Node Label to Relationship Type rules are being respected
- You could perhaps use [triggers](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/operational/triggers/) to check/act on any specific rules
- You may choose to create user defined [rules engine](https://maxdemarzi.com/2018/01/14/dynamic-rule-based-decision-trees-in-neo4j/)

There will be other approaches too.